# ASPX add HTML content programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a simple `ASPX` page that inherits from `MasterPage`:

(Popup.master)

```
<div class="text_container">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">    
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

(Privacy.aspx)
    
        Privacy

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

I need to add a HTML content inside the Privacy.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Privacy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentPlaceHolder body = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I saw this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.ASPX) but as I see I need asp control inside.
How to add just HTML content to `ContentPlaceHolder1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ContentPlaceHolder is intended to give you the ability to add controls in your page markup with a Content control and have them appear within the context of your master page.  Given that, in Privacy.aspx you can add a generic html control in `BodyContent` Content Control and set the InnerContent property on the added control within your code behind.

**Markup**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
             runat="server">
    <span id="SpanContent" runat="server"></span>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SpanContent.InnerHtml = "<b>Hello!</b>";
}
```